# How to prove Gegenbauer's addition theorem?

Tags: special-functions

How can one prove the following identity:
$$
    V_k(r_1, r_2)
        = {2k+1\over 2 r_1 r_2}\int_{|r_1 - r_2|}^{r_1+r_2}
        e^{-{r\over D}}
            P_k\left(r_1^2 - r^2 + r_2^2 \over 2 r_1 r_2 \right) d r=
$$
$$
=(2k+1)
    {I_{k+{1\over2}}\left(r_<\over D\right) \over \sqrt{r_<}}
    {K_{k+{1\over2}}\left(r_>\over D\right) \over \sqrt{r_>}}
$$
?
Here $r_<=\min(r_1, r_2)$, $r_>=\max(r_1, r_2)$, $I_\nu$ and $K_\nu$ are the modified Bessel functions of the first and second kind, $P_k(x)$ are Legendre polynomials and $k=0, 1, 2, 3, \dots$.

I verified the identity numerically, so I know that it works, but I didn't figure out how one could prove it. I know it has something to do with Gegenbauer's addition theorem and the equation 10.23.8 at [1]. The $V_k(r_1, r_2)$ is just the coefficient in the Legendre expansion of:
$$
{e^{{|{\bf r}_1 - {\bf r}_2|}\over D}\over |{\bf r}_1 - {\bf r}_2|}
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty V_k(r_1, r_2) P_k(\cos\theta)
$$
Note: when $D\to\infty$, then $V_k$ becomes ${r_<^k \over r_>^{k+1}}$, which follows from the properties of the Bessel functions and this is just the well known multipole expansion [2].

[1] http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.23#E8

[2] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Applications_of_Legendre_polynomials_in_physics

Comment: Cross-listed to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41167/2451